# Qt3 / Vs2003 - breakpoints etc, not working

Tags: qt, qt3

I've inherited a Qt3/Vs2003 project. Which I think's been badly mangled over the years, e.g. there was a new DEBUG macro added to it that was logging to file... opening the solution in VS and checking the build configurations I found there was no debug config (which I've added by copying the release config?) but it's not stopping at breakpoints (although it was at one point, now no longer playing - note: I do appear to be generating PDBs).

So how well should this integrate?
Should breakpoints, code completion etc work or am I expecting too much?

The only integration I've seen is the opening of a UI with Qt designer when I click on the ui in VS.

more...
it's in CVS, does QT have to be checked out with LF line endings?, this is mangling my VDProj?

Shouldn't the compiler output be put in the Release (or Debug) folder, mine's getting dumped in the same folder as the solution.

Comment: I'm happy to scrap the solution and to readd each project in individually if this proves to be the easiest way to sort it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a debug build config, then added a path to the debug symbols and working directory, tried it again and it worked. All the project options appear to be more or less unset (hence the drop location for the exe etc.)